# Copiar hasta cierto caracter en especifico. Excel y visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy trabajando en un programa usando VB y EXCEL. Actualmente tengo que copiar cierta información de unas celdas a otras para generar un reporte. Todo por ahora va funcionando bien. Pero tengo la siguiente duda.

Una de las cedas, contiene el historia de notas agregado por el usuario. Se estableció que luego de cada nota se ingrese el símbolo '#' para aclarar que la nota llega hasta ahí. La celda contiene algo así.

> 2017-08-03 11:06 by Sojo, Andres La propuesta fue cancelada por petición del cliente el día 3/8/2017. #
>
> 2017-07-18 09:47 by Sojo, Andres Continuamos ala espera del VoBo por
>   parte del cliente. #
>
> 2017-07-14 09:52 by Sojo, Andres Continuamos ala espera del VoBo por
>   parte del cliente.#
>
> 2017-07-03 15:14 by Sojo, Andres La propuesta se encuentra en revisión
>   por parte de KOF.#

Estoy utilizando el siguiente codigo, para copiar la informacion de la celda en el reporte que necesito.

```
Sheets("Extract").Range("AI" & sourceRow & "").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Print").Range("G" & destRow + 7 & "")
```

Pero esto me copia toda la información de la celda y solamente ocupo que copie hasta donde aparece el primer '#' y deje de copiar el resto.

Pense en hacer algo como un

```
Do
   copiar información de la celda 
While
   no aparezca el carácter #
```

Lo que sucede es que con un código como ese me va a copiar todo, dado que la información se encuentra en una sola celda no en varias.

Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: tendrias que extraer el texto a un string, y despues cortarlo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carlos, te recomiendo que obtengas primero el valor de la celda y recortes la misma desde la izquierda hasta la primer ocurrencia del caracter `#`. El código sería algo así:

```
texto = Sheets("Extract").Range("AI" & sourceRow & "")
texto = Left(texto, InStr(1, texto, "#") - 1)
Sheets("Print").Range("G" & destRow + 7 & "") = texto
```

Hacemos uso de [`instr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) para obtener la posición del caracter `#` y de [`left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/y050k1wb(v=vs.90).aspx) para recortar hasta dicha posición menos uno (para quitar el caracter final).

**Nota Importante**: Tener en cuenta que el anterior código dará un error en caso de no encontrar el caracter `#`, o bien verificamos que exista mediante `if InStr(1, texto, "#") > 0` o bien controlamos el error con un `On error`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciono a la perfección.